Launching a service from SLURM task prolog script fails
On the HPC I work with, I have to use docker in rootless-mode by calling a script start-docker.sh on every job.
To automate this, I would like to use the --task-prolog argument of srun and have the script called from a task_prolog.sh script:
#!/usr/bin/env sh
nohup start-docker.sh > docker-server.log 2&>1 &

With start-docker.sh responsible to launch dockerd-rootless.sh:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source /tmp/slurm/username/env.txt
dockerd-rootless.sh --host=$DOCKER_HOST --data-root=/storage/docker-data/username/ --exec-root=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/

The SLURM documentation for prolog scripts shows examples of setting environment variables or printing messages but nothing for executing a script.
Using this approach, despite the start-docker.sh script being launched, no docker-server is running.
Inspection of docker-server.log shows that the dockerd-rootless.sh script is called too, but seems ultimately interrupted when calling rootlesskit as it is the last command logged:
+ exec rootlesskit --state-dir=/run/user/8076/dockerd-rootless --net=slirp4netns --mtu=65520 --slirp4netns-sandbox=auto --slirp4netns-seccomp=auto --disable-host-loopback --port-driver=builtin --copy-up=/etc --copy-up=/run --propagation=rslave /usr/bin/dockerd-rootless.sh --host=unix:///run/user/8076/docker.sock --data-root=/storage/docker-data/username/ --exec-root=/run/user/8076/

Nonetheless, when start-docker.sh is called manually, additional lines are logged after the one from rootlesskit and the docker server runs as expected.
I don't understand why the script seems interrupted. Is the process running the prolog script killed at some point?
Thanks for your help.

At a guess I would think this is because docker takes some time to start up. By using & you are immediately moving on to the next command, but are not waiting until docker is ready. Maybe after you do start-docker.sh & try docker version in a loop until you get a zero response. eg. until docker version; do sleep 1; done. You'll want to add some timeout option in case docker fails to start entirely.

Thanks. Logging the output of task_prolog.sh shows that docker daemon starts correctly. Unfortunately, within the SLURM job, I still get Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///run/user/8076/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Perhaps you want --task-prolog instead of --prolog. Docs suggest that --prolog runs on the node where you invoked srun, and --task-prog runs on the actual node that runs your task. I have no experience with slurm, so that's as much help as I can offer.

sorry, I made a confusion while writing the question, but I'm indeed talking about task-prolog (I double checked by echoing hostname). I edited the question. Thanks for pointing that out.
